# Postgres defining custom properties - unrecognized configuration parameter or syntax error

Tags: postgresql

I want to define a custom property to set user id. I added the property to postgressql.conf

```
user = ''
```

It either gives syntax error or unrecognized configuration parameter

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that the configuration property should be in a format and some keywords are not allowed.

```
user - won't work
app_user - won't work
app.user - won't work
foo.bar - works
app._user - works
```

And we do not even have to add it to postgressql.conf